# dplyr applying formula to a group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have written a function that involves a bit of 'wrangling' with dplyr.
I'm having issues passing variable names to the function.

Here is the beginning of my function:
I put comments where I"m having trouble.
I tried the curly brackets around the variable, and curly brackets within fct_reorder.
But I keep getting error messages.

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = "Bead_Numb" == fct_reorder("Bead_Numb", mean_conc)`.
Caused by error in `fct_reorder()`:
! length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```
nano_jst_conc_1fct_ord<-function(dat,fct1,y1,y2,title){
  dat_summ<-
    dat %>%
    group_by_(fct1) %>%
    summarise(mean_conc = mean(Nucleic.Acid.Conc.), mean260_280=mean(X260.280),mean_260_230=mean(X260.230),
              CV_conc=(sd(Nucleic.Acid.Conc.)/mean(Nucleic.Acid.Conc.))*100,
              sd_conc=sd(Nucleic.Acid.Conc.),IQR=IQR(Nucleic.Acid.Conc.),Q75=quantile(Nucleic.Acid.Conc.,probs=0.75))##
  y1=y1
  y2=y2
  ##
  datM_summ<-full_join(dat,dat_summ,by=fct1)
**### this is where I'm having trouble because I want to change the variable that I want to mutate ##**
  datM_ord<-datM_summ %>%
    mutate({{fct1}}==fct_reorder(fct1,mean_conc))
  ##
  ggplot(datM_ord, aes_string(x=fct1,fill=fct1, y="Nucleic.Acid.Conc.")) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

here is my data:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(Sample.ID = c("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", 
"G1", "H1", "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "A3", 
"B3", "C3", "D3", "E3", "F3", "G3", "H3", "A4", "B4", "C4", "D4", 
"E4", "F4", "G4", "H4", "A5", "B5", "C5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "G5", 
"H5", "A6", "B6", "C6", "D6", "E6", "F6", "G6", "H6", "A7", "B7", 
"C7", "D7", "E7", "F7", "G7", "H7", "A8", "B8", "C8", "D8", "E8", 
"F8", "G8", "H8", "A9", "B9", "C9", "D9", "E9", "F9", "G9", "H9", 
"A10", "B10", "C10", "D10", "E10", "F10", "G10", "H10", "A11", 
"B11", "C11", "D11", "E11", "F11", "G11", "H11"), Bead_Numb = c("bead_1", 
"bead_1", "bead_1", "bead_1", "bead_2", "bead_2", "bead_2", "bead_2", 
"bead_3", "bead_3", "bead_3", "bead_3", "bead_4", "bead_4", "bead_4", 
"bead_4", "bead_5", "bead_5", "bead_5", "bead_5", "bead_6", "bead_6", 
"bead_6", "bead_6", "bead_7", "bead_7", "bead_7", "bead_7", "bead_8", 
"bead_8", "bead_8", "bead_8", "bead_9", "bead_9", "bead_9", "bead_9", 
"bead_10", "bead_10", "bead_10", "bead_10", "bead_11", "bead_11", 
"bead_11", "bead_11", "bead_12", "bead_12", "bead_12", "bead_12", 
"bead_13", "bead_13", "bead_13", "bead_13", "bead_14", "bead_14", 
"bead_14", "bead_14", "bead_15", "bead_15", "bead_15", "bead_15", 
"bead_16", "bead_16", "bead_16", "bead_16", "bead_17", "bead_17", 
"bead_17", "bead_17", "bead_18", "bead_18", "bead_18", "bead_18", 
"bead_19", "bead_19", "bead_19", "bead_19", "bead_20", "bead_20", 
"bead_20", "bead_20", "bead_21", "bead_21", "bead_21", "bead_21", 
"bead_22", "bead_22", "bead_22", "bead_22"), Nucleic.Acid.Conc. = c(124.2, 
111.1, 110.6, 88.5, 53.5, 52.6, 50.4, 47.2, 76.8, 81.6, 79.2, 
71, 112.2, 105.2, 117.8, 121.6, 116, 104.8, 104, 105.1, 104.5, 
109.8, 111.3, 109.2, 124.5, 110.1, 121, 117.2, 87, 89.2, 65.8, 
74.8, 93.3, 90.3, 96.4, 98.4, 92.2, 92.4, 101.1, 99.3, 82.5, 
76.4, 78.4, 71.7, 76.7, 78.5, 70.1, 65.2, 78.5, 76.1, 79.3, 68.6, 
123.9, 122.3, 128.2, 131.8, 117, 115.4, 111.3, 108.9, 114, 105.7, 
82.9, 94.3, 120.2, 70.1, 114, 72, 87.3, 93.3, 95.8, 97.6, 65.6, 
57.8, 68.1, 54.9, 68.2, 66.7, 70.6, 69.6, 119.6, 119.8, 114.6, 
115.4, 104.6, 102.3, 107, 105.2), X260.280 = c(1.97, 1.98, 1.93, 
1.97, 1.99, 2.02, 1.99, 2.04, 2.02, 2.02, 2.03, 2.02, 1.98, 1.99, 
1.97, 1.96, 2.01, 2.01, 2.03, 2.01, 2.01, 2.01, 2.01, 2.01, 2, 
2.01, 2, 2.01, 2.02, 2.01, 2.01, 2, 1.99, 2, 1.98, 2.02, 1.91, 
1.94, 1.93, 1.92, 2.03, 2.03, 2.02, 2.03, 2.02, 2.03, 2.03, 2.03, 
2.01, 2.01, 2.03, 2.02, 1.99, 2.03, 1.99, 1.99, 2, 1.99, 1.98, 
2.01, 2, 1.99, 1.98, 1.98, 2.02, 2.01, 1.99, 2, 2.06, 2, 2.02, 
2.01, 2.01, 2.01, 1.93, 2.02, 2.02, 2.01, 2.02, 2.04, 2.03, 2.04, 
2.04, 2.03, 2.01, 2.02, 2, 2.01), X260.230 = c(1.96, 2.01, 1.8, 
1.93, 1.96, 2.06, 1.92, 2.04, 2.06, 2.1, 2.11, 2.09, 1.81, 1.82, 
1.77, 1.65, 1.9, 1.96, 1.89, 1.91, 2.06, 2.05, 2.1, 2.11, 2.03, 
2.03, 1.98, 2.01, 1.95, 1.98, 1.91, 1.94, 1.86, 1.92, 1.86, 1.91, 
1.37, 1.36, 1.35, 1.26, 2.13, 2.14, 2.12, 2.11, 2.11, 2.13, 2.11, 
2.12, 2.11, 2.09, 2.13, 2.07, 1.94, 1.95, 1.9, 1.92, 1.97, 1.95, 
1.84, 1.96, 1.99, 2, 1.84, 1.88, 2.14, 2.06, 2.12, 2.05, 2.16, 
2.11, 2.1, 2.17, 2.07, 2.08, 1.63, 2.07, 2.08, 2.1, 2.11, 2.11, 
2.12, 2.1, 2.1, 2.09, 2.12, 2.12, 2.11, 2.12), Method = c("50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol", 
"50%_ethanol", "50%_ethanol")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-88L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems here, but the main one is that if you want to use a variable name on the left hand side of an argument inside `mutate`, you need to use the curly-curly operator around the variable, and use the walrus operator `:=` rather than `=` (and certainly not `==`). In your case that would be something like `mutate({{fct1}} := fct_reorder({{fct1}}, mean_conc))`

A  few other points are

- `group_by_` and `aes_string` are both deprecated. You can use tidy evaluation inside `group_by` and `aes` instead.
- You use `fct1` in places without the curly-curly when it needs one
- You don't use the `y1`, `y2` or `title` parameters inside your function
- Since your function outputs a plot, you are wasting lines and computing power by calculating variables you don't use in your plot.
- You store intermediate objects when you could just use the pipe (there's nothing *wrong* with this, but since you are using the pipe elsewhere...)
- It's poor function design to specify variables inside your function. This means the function can't be used if your data frame changes, and you can't reuse your function elsewhere.
- Your code is very hard to read because you don't put spaces around operators, and you allow your code lines to be too long. Don't underestimate the importance of this; it's not just for aesthetic reasons, but code without tidy formatting is much more prone to bugs and is difficult to debug.

Taking all this into account, you could rewrite your function like this:

```r
nano_jst_conc_1fct_ord <- function(dat, fct1, yvar, title) {
  
  cols <- deparse(substitute(fct1))
  
  left_join(dat,
            dat %>%
              group_by({{fct1}}) %>%
              summarise(neworder := mean({{yvar}})),
            by = cols) %>%
    mutate({{fct1}} := fct_reorder({{fct1}}, neworder)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = {{fct1}}, fill = {{fct1}}, y = {{yvar}})) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    guides(fill = "none") +
    ggtitle(title)
}
```

Which allows:

```r
nano_jst_conc_1fct_ord(dat, Bead_Numb, Nucleic.Acid.Conc., "Concentration plot")
```

[image]

Or

```r
nano_jst_conc_1fct_ord(dat, Method, X260.230, NULL)
```

[image]

and even

```r
nano_jst_conc_1fct_ord(iris, Species, Petal.Length, "Use on other datasets")
```

[image]

We now have a function that works, uses all its arguments, doesn't use deprecated functions, is easy to read, and can be applied to other datasets.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I actually didn't paste my whole function, so later in the plot I used y1 and y2 for the height of some geom_text.

Comment: could you please explain : cols <- deparse(substitute(fct1))